# Timer to control the object in XNA

Tags: xna

I thought this was a great concept; a method that is activated from the constructor when the object is created and in the method, see code below, after 3 seconds call another object to remove it from a list, but unfortunately this isn't working the way I want! There seems to be some problems with the timer, because the call to remove the object is done immediately without any delay! Have I missed something or isn't this possible? Perhaps in another way?

```
public void ExplosionTimer(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        seconds += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (seconds > 3)
            objectManager.ExplosionControl(); 
    }
```

Comment: Why not just handle this in the object's Update()? Seems pointless to add another thread and have to worry about sync, etc when the functionality is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the method activated from the constructor do? Allow the gameobject to be explodable? Are you setting seconds = 0 in the constructor? What does objectManager.ExplosionControl() do? Loop over all objects and find the ones with seconds > 3? If so, why don't you just pass the object itself and ask it to be removed from the list?

```
objectManager.removeExplodedObject( this ); // for example
```

What you are describing should work. Are you calling ExplosionTimer on each update?

Comment: Thanks! Each object have there own update method and when I made a call to the ExplosionTimer from the update, then it worked like I wanted!

Comment: I'm just a little bit confused how the GameTime object works!? Does the seconds variable start to count the first time the ExplosionTimer is called?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to you problem but simply an alternative to your timer logic.
You could also define a field that stores the time in the future when you want to trigger your behaviour.

The following example will cause damage & trigger a particle effect every half second regardles if this method is called more often than that period.

```
  private double _particleTimeSpan;

  public override void OnHurt(Vector2 location, float amount, DamageTypeEnum type, Actor cause, GameTime gameTime)
  {
    if (_particleTimeSpan < gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds)
    {
        _hurtParticle.Trigger(location);
         Health -= amount;
        _particleTimeSpan = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds + 0.5;
    }
  }
```